# App deep linking not supported on Latest Firefox for Android 36.0

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, deep-linking

I have a android app in which I have defined my intent filter to handle any http request to my website to open in the app I have built. On Chrome, I get the prompt to open in app but not on Firefox. Is this not implemented on Firefox yet?

```
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="www.mysite.com"
                  android:pathPattern="/.*"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see an android icon appearing in url bar. Click it takes me to the deep link app. Unlike other browses reaction though. :(
[image]